# Running Rails Server in a UNIX socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, thin

Is it possible to run `rails server` in a UNIX socket?

I ask because `rails server` gives such a beautiful output, and it's really easy to distinguish SQL queries from HTTP requests, etc. But, I'm using Nginx, so I'd like to connect the application server with it using UNIX sockets, but I'm having some trouble.

The following command results in an error:

```
bundle exec rails server thin --socket=/var/run/rails_app.sock
```

It is seemingly trying to parse `--socket` as an option on `rails server`, not `thin`. Is there any way around this, or am I stuck using `thin start` and succumbing to a less beautiful log output?

Comment: You mean , in development or in production?

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
bundle exec rails server thin -- --socket=/var/run/rails_app.sock
```

`--` is used to mark the end of parameters for the first command on a lot of *nix apps.

From `man sh`:

```
   --        A  --  signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the --
             are treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

Comment: That doesn’t work. The `--` stops the arguments to `bundle exec`, of which `rails server thin` is part of.